# Perl regex for allowing all the special charecters

Tags: perl, pcre

The environment I am working is on PCRE which supports Perl syntax.

I want to build a regular expression which supports all the charecters and special charecters.

I have tried

```
  (.*)
```

But it does not work.

For example. I am trying to redirect

From

```
https://oldaddress.com/select.do?cyuf=err%3Errt.com%3fsfds%4A222-3424234&p=66&j=8
```

To

```
https://newsite.com/select.do?cyuf=err%3Errt.com%3fsfds%4A222-3424234&p=66&j=8
```

The old site `oldaddress.com` successfully redirects to `newsite.com` but the URI part `select.do?cyuf=err%3Errt.com%3fsfds%4A222-3424234&p=66&j=8` does not remain in it.

I have used `regEx =~ (^.*)` to handle the URI part but the regex does not support all the special characters.

I would like to implement this regEx in Perl.

Comment: Add someexample and descripe what "But it does not work." means

Comment: `.` captures most stuff. If you want it to catch everything, you might need to also include `ms` on your regex modifier, so it'll match multiple lines and linefeeds.

Comment: I would like to allow $, % which are special charecters.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. What programming language are you using? Do you want to replace part of the `https://oldaddress.com/select` with `newsite`? Why are  `$` and `%` relevant? `$` is not even in the URL you have shown as input.

Comment: The special charecters in the URI  ? and % does not get append properly. the %3 changes to %253. The whole thing I am handling through Perl Regex. I would like to know a Perl regex which supports special charecters as well

Comment: You may find that's happening before the regex, because of interpolation. But check out `quotemeta` which'll escape meta characters.

Comment: should I use as regex =~(quotemeta)

Comment: Can't answer. Show us some code, and I might be able to. But actually, I suspect we'll find there's a different problem entirely if you do that.

Comment: @Sobrique: The `/m` "multiple lines" modifier affects only `^` and `$`, so only `/s` is relevant here. But dot `.` matches everything except a newline character anyway, and URLs may not contain control characters

Comment: @Borodin (.*) does not match all the charecters such as ?, %..  how to handle special charecters ?, % using Regex using Perl.. All my question is that

Comment: In Perl regexes, a dot matches all characters except a newline. So, yes, it does match ? and %.

Comment: The regex (.*) do not handle this part    ?cyuf=err%3Errt.com%3fsfds%4A222-3424234&p=66&j=8   where it is not able to recognize ?

Comment: If that's true, then your PCRE is not as Perl compatible as it claims to be. But, as I've patiently tried to explain in my answer below, you don't need to match parts of your input string that you aren't changing.

Comment: Are you using mod_rewrite? Perl? Python? JavaScript? We have no idea, because even after all this back-and-forth, you **still** haven't posted any actual code!

Comment: @MattJacob: From his other questions, I'm guessing it's a PCRE implementation in Java. But you're right over the last three hours he has posted almost no useful information about the problem.

Comment: @Dave  thanks for the clarification, @ Jacob: I am working on Oracle Iplanet which supports PCRE. I have tried a lot for (.*) to support ? and % but I think something is happening over there.

Comment: @Sawyer: One last try - **please** post your code.

Comment: Your pseudocode: `regEx =~ (^.*)` makes no sense. Based on what you're trying to do, it should be something like `$string_containing_url =~ /(.*)/;`

Comment: If it helps to hear it from another voice, a dot `.` in PCRE matches *all characters except linefeed*. That includes question mark `?` and percent sign `%`, so your diagnosis is *wrong* and the query part of the URL is missing for a *different reason*. If you showed your code then I am sure we would be able to help you very quickly

Comment: @Borodin I think we all would have gotten more useful feedback if we had just piped our comments to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Ok. The question as it stands is unanswerable and the OP seems strangely reticent to actually answer any requests for clarification. So I've voted to close the question. Happy to vote for re-opening if anything becomes clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is almost certainly not with your regex. The query parameters don't change, so they shouldn't be included in the regex at all as this Perl code will demonstrate:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $url = 'https://oldaddress.com/select.do?cyuf=err%3Errt.com%3fsfds%4A222-3424234&p=66&j=8';

my $new_url = 'https://newsite.com/select.do?cyuf=err%3Errt.com%3fsfds%4A222-3424234&p=66&j=8';

$url =~ s/oldaddress/newsite/;

if ($url eq $new_url) {
  say "Looks like that worked";
} else {
  say "Looks like you've got a problem";
}
```

I'm only changing the domain, so that's all I need to refer to in the regex.

If your query string isn't surviving the transformation, then that problem is down to some other problem in the technology that you are using. Without knowing more about what you're doing, we really can't be any more help.

**Update:** From Sawyer's comment

> but how to handle special charecters ?, % using Regex using Perl

You don't seem to be reading what people are telling you.

1. Your regex doesn't need to handle ?, % or other special characters. Your regex only needs to deal with the bits of your string that are changing - that's the domain names and they don't include these characters.
2. `%` has no special meaning in Perl regular expressions.
3. `?` has a special meaning, you avoid that by escaping it with a backslash (so use `\?`).
4. A dot (`.`) in a Perl regular expression matches **any character** except a newline. It matches `?` and `%` without any problems at all.

Your problem is not with your regex; it is somewhere else in your system. But because you are being so mysterious about what you're doing and how you're doing it, we really can't be any more help.

**Update2:** Here's another version of my program which demonstrates `(.*)` matching `?` and `%`. But I can't emphasise enough that **you don't need to do this**.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $url = 'https://oldaddress.com/select.do?cyuf=err%3Errt.com%3fsfds%4A222-3424234&p=66&j=8';

my $new_url = 'https://newsite.com/select.do?cyuf=err%3Errt.com%3fsfds%4A222-3424234&p=66&j=8';

$url =~ s/(.*)oldaddress(.)/${1}newsite${2}/;

if ($url eq $new_url) {
  say "Looks like that worked";
} else {
  say "Looks like you've got a problem";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cross for the example but how to handle special charecters  ?, % using Regex using Perl. All my question is that

Comment: See edit to my answer. Those are not special characters.